# Loading PowerShell Cmdlet Assembly with Module Manifest

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make my way through the PowerShell documentation and have hit a point of confusion.

I have creating a cmdlet assembly using the sample code located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901838(v=vs.85).aspx).

I can load the *module* by issuing the command:

```
Import-Module -Name *NameOfAssembly*
```

This is, of course, if the assembly is located in a folder where PowerShell can find it.

If I create a module manifest, the only way I have been able to get the module manifest to load the assembly is to add the assembly on the `RequiredModules` line of the manifest.  The documentation (located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337(v=vs.85).aspx)) states that this doesn't actually load any modules.  From what I have observed this is contradictory to what actually happens.  Am I reading / understanding this incorrectly?  If not, what am I missing?  Is there a better way to get a cmdlet assembly (or assemblies) (I think they are called binary modules) *deployed*?

Comment: Set this before `Import-Module`: `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference='None'`. BTW to load modules you need to use `RootModule` or `NestedModules` manifest key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - same as it works with script modules, you can get loading of `NameOfModule.dll` by simply putting it in `NameOfModule` subfolder of any folders listed in `$env:PSModulePath`

```
$dir = mkdir $profile\..\Modules\Greetings -Force
$dllPath = Join-Path -Path $dir.FullName -ChildPath Greetings.dll
Add-Type @'
using System.Management.Automation;
namespace SendGreeting
{
  [Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Send, "Greeting")]
  public class SendGreetingCommand : Cmdlet
  {
    [Parameter(Mandatory=true)]
    public string Name
    {
      get { return name; }
      set { name = value; }
    }
    private string name;
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
      WriteObject("Hello " + name + "!");
    }
  }
}
'@ -OutputAssembly $dllPath
Import-Module Greetings -PassThru
```

In case you really need manifest (e.g. for some metadata, or external files) you have two options, depending on PowerShell version:

- v2 - ModulesToProcess (works with newer versions, but causes warning)
- v3+ - RootModule (fails on v2)

The key you've used, `RequiredModules`, is there to provide a way to name your dependencies. E.g. modules that your code depends on. `RequiredAssemblies` kind-of works, because adding any assembly that contains PowerShell cmdlets "just works" - but that approach kind of "hides" from future user where you defined your commands.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When I first read your response, I didn't think it was going to work as I had tried setting the `RootModule` parameter before (or so I thought).  I think the key thing I was forgetting was to execute the command `Remove-Module` before executing `Import-Module` after I made changes to the manifest.  The other thing I discovered (using the script you included in your response) is that I also needed to set the value of the `CmdletsToExport` parameter as well.  Everything is working as I would expect now.

Comment: BTW: If you want to guarantee that module is re-imported, you can run `Import-Module` with `-Force` parameter - it will remove module for you in the background (if already loaded).